# Фамилии русских богатырей

Tags: история

Может быть, вопрос больше исторический, нежели лингвистический. Но я тут задумалась: фамилия Ильи Муромца известна - Гущин. А вот как быть с фамилиями двух других - Алеши Поповича и Добрыни Никитича? Причем, если у Добрыни известно хотя бы отчество, то насчет Алеши только то, что он - сын священника (кстати, я слышала, что он не Алексей, а Александр).
И еще пришло в голову: у Добрыни Никитича из них единственное имя не по святцам (или в святцах есть имя Добрыня?).
Может быть, кто-то знает. Буду очень благодарна за информацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу сказать лишь о Добрыне. Он служил Святославу, а тот был известным противником христианизации Руси( кстати, имя Святослав церковь не признаёт), и после восхождения Владимира на престол, Добрыня не сразу согласился принять христианство. Имя это по сути языческое, а когда шла христианизация Руси, всё языческое стремились уничтожить или предать анафеме. У Э.Скобелева есть книга "Мирослав, князь дреговичский", отчасти она написана на старорусском, там можно кое-что почерпнуть о житие Добрыни.

Comment: Но интересно, что отчество у Добрыни вполне христианское

Answer (score 0):

Ну, начнём с того, что образ любого из этих богатырей суть образ собирательный, созданный из различных преданий, объединённых к тому или иному герою.

Начнём с **Ильи Муромца**. По хрестоматийной версии - родом из деревни Карачарово, на Муромщине, потому и Муромец. Однако деревень с названием *Карачары-Карачарово*, помимо Владимирщины (где город Муром), несколько: в Чувашии, в Тверской области, в Нижегородской области, на Смоленщине. Я уж не говорю о карачаровцах - тюркском народе, живущем на Кубани. А в древнерусской летописи, повествующей о военных действиях русских князей против половцев, тоже упоминается населённый пункт *Карачары* (к сожалению, я не сохранил ссылку на эту летопись). Согласитесь, что топать из этих Карачар пешедралом в Киев ко двору князя Владимира гораздо ближе и реальнее, чем из-под Мурома. Или, хотя бы, со смоленского Карачарово - тоже куда ближе. А теперь задумаемся: времена князя Владимира Красно Солнышко, Русь только-только крестилась, а простой деревенский мужик **Илья**, в возрасте полных 33 года, уже носит христианское имя!? А имя-то **Илья** по происхождению - еврейское (*ветх./зав. пророк Илья*), у евреев (=хазар) оно ходовое, как и у православных!...

А теперь, насчёт **МУРОМЕЦ**. В старо-немецком фольклоре проскакивает предание о русском (именно, русском!) богатыре по имени **Илья Моравин**. **МОРАВИН** соответствует еврейскому имени **МЕРОВ**, - еврейские фамилии типа Моравский, Муравский, Муравчук и т.п. Так как всё-таки правильней? - **Моравин/Меров** или переделанный московитами **Муромец** из-под *муромских Карачар*?! Сын "русского" богатыря **Ильи** звался **Сокольничек**. От птицы *сокол*? - птица сокол на древнерусском языке называлась *Рарог*/*Ререг*. А посмотрите, сколько среди подтверждённых евреев Соколов, Соколовых, Соколецких, Соколовских, Соколинских, - **Электронная книга памяти воинов-евреев, павших в боях с нацизмом**, графа Мемориал, внизу страницы алфавитный указатель, смотрите на СОКОЛ - [link text](http://jmemory.org/).

Противником Ильи был **Соловей-разбойник**. Киношники и мультипликаторы изображают его в виде птицеподобного чудища, хотя в самом тексте былины нет ни полслова о его птице-подобии. К тому же, соловей не свищет по-разбойничьи, а издаёт нежные трели. И в древнерусском языке нет слова *соловей* - эта птица по др./русски называлась *Щек* или *Щекот*. Я уверяю Вас, что этот **Соловей**-разбойник имел вполне человеческий облик, а **СОЛОВ**(+ей) это еврейское (=хазарское) имя. На том же сайте посмотрите евреев: Соловей, Соловьев, Соловейчик, Соловьёвский, Славин, Славинский, Славский, Славный (на СЛАВ - этих очень много!) . ===================================================================================== Теперь перейдём к **Добрыне Никитичу** . Имя **Добрыня** это от "добрый"? А почему не от еврейского (=хазарского) имени **Дебор** (*ветх./зав. пророчица Дебора*)? Матерью князя Владимира Красно Солнышко была хазарка Малуша (Малка). Её братом был княжеский командир по имени **Довр** = **Добр** - ивритная буква **ב** бет озвучивается, как Б и, как В. Вот вам и **Добрыня**, который вместе с Путятой крестил новгородцев, силой загнав их в реку Волхов. Отчество **НИКИТИЧ**. Христианское имя *Никита* от греческого *Ника*? Я уже неоднократно писал в своих публикациях на этом сайте, что большинство "греческих" имён раннехристианских святых суть греко-византийская переделка еврейских имён - первые христиане были диаспорными евреями, их жития тоже переиначивались византийскими редакторами (этот раннехристианский период историки называют "*иудеохристианство*"). А теперь посмотрите на том же сайте еврейские фамилии на НИК- , НИХ- , НЕХ- . Находятся таковые!...  Добавим , что на Украине не Никита , а Микита ( равно , как не Николай , а Микола ) . Я уже отвечал , ранее , в других Вопросах о связи ивритных первоисходников с разницей русских и украинских именных форм . Есть ивритное имя Ихт , см. еврейскую фамилию Ихтейман , у которой существуют дополнительные диалектные формы на Н или М , - в  диалектах иврита такое добавление согласных отмечено . Это типа , как еврейское имя Остап(Астафий) - у мусульман Мустафа ; или каламбур "подводная лодка Акула-Макула - пол-года плавала , два года тонула в пьесе Б. Лавренёва "Разлом" (Акулина тоже ивритное имя ) . В России прижились варианты с Н - Никита и Николай , а на Украине варианты с М - Микита и Микола , - всё через иврит . ===================================================================================== Наконец, **Алёша Попович**. Хронологически самый младший из богатырей. Раз **ПОПОВИЧ**, значит **сын попа**, церковного батюшки? Вообще-то, в былинах про Алёшу о его родителях сказано очень-очень мало и мимоходом (*и скорее всего, это поздняя вставка*). Но дело даже не в этом. Ну не говорили никогда на Руси - Алексей *Землепашцевич*, Алексей *Сапожникович*, Алексей *Лесорубович* и т.п. **Поп** это еврейское имя, соответствующее итальянскому *Пипино*, западно-европейскому Пеппи (*сказочка "Пеппи Длинный Чулок"*) или английской мисс совершенство Мэри *Поппинс* [link text](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CC%FD%F0%E8_%CF%EE%EF%EF%E8%ED%F1). Смотрите на том же сайте фамилии подтверждённых евреев на ПОП-: Поперман, Попик, Попков, Поповский, Поплавский и др. (очень много!). Посмотрите и на ПАП- - тоже хватает! Вообще, есть православное имя *Фафуил*, см. Православный календарь на **Ф** [link text](http://days.pravoslavie.ru/ABC/mf.htm#fafuil) (святой, который за просто так раздает подарки) - это тот же **Поп**/**Пап**, так как ивритная буква **פ**  пей читается двояко - П и Ф. А теперь имя **АЛЁША**. Ну, чё это, вот, он уже вполне взрослый мужик, имеющий богатырские ратные подвиги, а всё *Алёша*, да *Алёша*?! И ни разу - *Алексей*!? А, ведь, есть узбекский поэт с мусульманским именем *Алишер* Навои. А большинство мусульманских имён это суть двойники имён еврейских (и, необязательно, из Писания). А украинский писатель *Олесь* Гончар? А белорусская *Олеся*? Посмотрите на том же сайте-мортирологе подтверждённых евреев: Алешин, Алешинский, Алешкевич, Алешкович, Алешников, Алещенко...  ///////

Теперь об **Александре Поповиче** (он же Александр Златогривый). Этот витязь - лицо историческое. Геройствовал в Липецкой битве, погиб в битве на Калке. В честь него новгородский князь Ярослав назвал своего сына Александром (ставшим потом Невским). Имя *Александр* ходовое имя у евреев - его дают в честь Александра Македонского, который благоволил к евреям, а вступив (не захватив штурмом) в Иерусалим, подъехал к храму, сошел с коня и демонстративно преклонил колени перед богом Яхве. На Руси до появления Александра Поповича имя *Александр* не просматривается. Об "отчестве" **ПОПОВИЧ** я уже сказал. =======================================================================================  Ну,  а теперь - **общий вывод**. **Древнерусские богатыри были хазарскими ландскнехтами на службе киевских князей. Со включениями в их подвиги хазарских преданий.**